# position attribute in CSS

Tags: css, position

Can you tell me the exact functioning of position attribute in css and difference in two values i.e "relative" and "absolute". Please tell me it in context of following code:
    
         I am absolute positioned

```
<section id="about" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages">
     <article>Simple Parallax Scroll</article>
</section>

#home { 
  background: url(home-bg.jpg) 50% 0 repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px; 
  height: 1000px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 1920px; 
  position: relative; 
}

#home article { 
  height: 458px; 
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center; 
  top: 150px; 
  width: 100%; 
}

#about { 
  background: url(about-bg.jpg) 50% 0 repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px; 
  height: 1000px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 1920px; 
  position: relative; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#about article { 
  height: 458px; 
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center; 
  top: 150px; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

And may you also the proper functioning of "-webkit-box-shadow" attribute.

Comment: Just clarifying you want us to explain the code? Not sure I understand.

Comment: no I don't want you to explain the code just the working of positioning attribute

Comment: they are both different. by default relative is a property of `html` or `body`. When you specify this, every child of that element will position around that div. This is the difference! You can see my answer and the references.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the difference:**

When you use position `relative` you are making a div that will be relative to other divs with position `absolute`. Absolute will basically make the div or that element float above the document. Without having to follow the current dom or what you call it.

When you are simply using `position: relative;` you are not placing the div any where. But you are actually just creating a relative point for other elements if there is no relative div the `position: absolute;` will be following the document as relative.

**From your css:**

In your content, by following the CSS `#home` will be relative and `#home article` will be placed over it. Where ever you want to place it. And similarly `#about article` will be placed over `#about`.

You will not figure out what is the main idea of `absolute` or `relative` untill you write this: `top: 0;` this will remove all the margins from top side its similar to this `margin-top: 0;`. You can also try to move the div as much as you want.

Positioning simply lets you move the elements without having to follow the dom(or whatever it is). The basic difference between them is that relative will be the main place or main point from where the placement would start for children of that element. And absolute will follow any nearest parent and will get a new position.

**Learn about them here:**

Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

W3school.com: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp (if you want to learn the basic).

CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

W3.org: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position

Comment: thanks for answer just one thing : "http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_relative" , this the link of a code . can you please tell me why the "h2.pos_right" is shifted to right even when they have given "left:20px" ??

Comment: Ok, `left: 20;` means 20px margin from left not closure to right. It means that this element can only have a max-margin of 20px from left. This way you can see that there is 20px from left and so it is pushed towards other side. When you try to give `right: 20;` it will get pushed towards left. Try it :)

Comment: ok so is it taking left margin relative to the last "h2.pos_left" and if I had given left: 40px; for last "h2.pos_left" and this "h2.pos_right" would be 20 from left??

Comment: When you will give `left: 40px` element will have 40px margin from left and so on. Thats what it meant

Comment: +1 For the detailed answer. But just a tip, linking to `w3schools` isn't fashionable on stackoverflow for very good reasons. You might wanna link to better tutorials.

Comment: hehe yes I know that! for that reason I just wrote (if you want to learn the basic). Otherwise I provided him with other 3 tutorials! :) That would be helpfull for him